# Arduino Stepper Library Working/AccelStepper Not Working

Tags: arduino

I am trying to control a 24V NEMA23 stepper motor using an ArduinoMega 2560 (R3).
I am using an ST-M5045 driver.

When I use the default Arduino Stepper library, the motor runs fine.

I am using pin 31 for the steps and pin 30 for the direction.

My code looks like:

```
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution

void setup() {
  pinMode(30,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(31,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(30,LOW);
  digitalWrite(31,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(31,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(31,LOW);
}
```

Now, I want to operate the same motor using AccelStepper but can't get any response.

My code looks lie:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper3(1, 31, 30);

void setup()
{ 
    stepper3.setMaxSpeed(400.0);
    stepper3.setAcceleration(100.0);
    stepper3.moveTo(100000);
}

void loop()
{
    stepper3.run();
}
```

Any idea on why this is not working?
I have tried several variations here with no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
James

Comment: Have you tried the [constant speed example](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/ConstantSpeed_8pde-example.html) of the library? of course you should use your definition for the stepper driver..

Comment: I have tried that as well, including variants where I put a 1, 2, and 4 as the first parameter of the AccelStepper definition.

Comment: Well, no, the `AccelStepper stepper3(1, 31, 30);` should remain that way if you have a stepper driver with "STEP" and "DIR" inputs... So it works with your original code but not with the example? Did you leave it running for a lot of time? Because it seems that your motor is really slow (in your code you are sending about 1M steps per second), so maybe it is just moving slowly...

Comment: That was it.  In the original code, I increased the maxspeed to 4000 and now I can see it move very slowly.  So, I will just play around with the speed until I get what I want.  Thanks so much.    If you put your comment as a answer, I can accept it and you get points (if you want them).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tests, it looks like the problem was just the speed.

The original code (the one with the manual pin movement) generated a very high frequency clock for the steps (I think close to 1MHz).

Consequently when using a max speed of 400 steps/s the user can think the motor is halted. In fact, however, the motor IS spinning, just too slow.

To be sure that the motor works, it is sufficient to check if the step pin on the controller is pulsed. Alternatively, just raise the speed to see the motor actually spinning.

One remark, though. Are all these steps really necessary? I mean, if the motor is really turning so slow, maybe it's because you set the driver in microstepping mode (maybe 32 or 64 pulses per step). If this is the case, maybe you should lower this, unless you really need very precise movements (but then you will have to sacrifice speed)

Comment: Again, great comment.  I probably have the microstepping switches set incorrectly. Looking at it, I have it set now to require 25600 steps/rev.  That is way too high.  If it was set to a much more reasonable number (like 3200), the original code would have worked.  Thanks again.

Comment: Can I ask a follow up?  How do you calculate the speed that should be specified in AccelStepper?  I am using a motor that says it uses 200 steps/rev.  Further, I have have the ST-M5045 set to 6400 pulses/rev, which I think corresponds to 32 microsteps.  When I use my non-AccellStepper code, the motor rips along.  When I use my AccelStepper code, it moves at maybe 1/4 the speed or slower.  For example, using the Random example code and putting 20000 as the base used, it is still very slow.  How do I increase the speed?  Thanks

Comment: @user1805103 well, I think that setting 20000 pulses/s means that it will make approx 3 revolutions per second. If it is slower, maybe the microcontroller is not fast enough, and so you can't go that fast. If this is your case, unluckily there is no solution other than choosing another board or, much better, setting the controller board to fewer steps/rev (after all, 6400 pulses/rev is really high)

Comment: The thing that perplexes me is that when I run the non-AccelStepper code, it is running really fast.  When I run the AccelStepper code, it runs maybe 1/4 the speed of the non-AccelStepper code.  That seems to indicate that there is something not right on the AccelStepper side of things rather than the board.

Comment: @user1805103 the fact is that the library has some code inside. Your code is just two digital writes and the loop; you can't go any faster. The library, on the other side, has at least a function call, some tests and the same digital writes as your code. If you need the speed of your code, then you won't be able to perform any control task; it's not a library fault, it's just that the microcontroller can't go any faster. If you try to implement a sort of logic in your code, you'll find that the motor will slow down. So the solutions are: 1) if you REALLY need this speed and resolution, then

Comment: use a more powerful uC; 2) if you don't, reduce the resolution of the stepper by reducing the microstepping control. But in my opinion if you need a fast motor you don't need very tiny steps, and if you need small steps then you don't need much speed. So avoid using a high microstepping value..

Answer (score 0):

I'm chiming in a little late to the ballgame here, but I had a similar problem 6 years later and the rest of the Internet was scarce on the details so I thought I'd post.

I'm using a DM320T Stepper Driver and my motor was not spinning.  I had to use this: setMinPulseWidth(20). That fixed all of my problems and it is now working.

The min pulse width of this stepper driver is something like 2.5 microseconds per documentation but I had to set it to 20 to achieve desired results.